InDesign: Optical margin alignment with guillemot

I have noticed that, with optical margin alignment enabled in InDesign, the double quotes are very satisfactorily pushed outside the margin, so that the text in the first two lines in the example image is perfectly aligned (with the font size of 12pt and optical margin setting of 18pt). But when I use the guillemots characters for quoting, the same effect doesn't occur (see the third line in the image). Why? Is there any setting I must tweak?

This could be a typeface related issue.
